# How to preload images through Ajax (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, preload

I have some Ajax-tabs that I made via [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). When I click on one of them I see a preloader while it's loading it's linked appropriate php-file and when it's done I can see the new content. So far so good.

The problem is that the appropriate tab doesn't preload its content's images. But I want some tabs that can preload their whole content (including images).

I read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image) that you can preload images through an Ajax-request but don't know how to do it with [jQuery UI-Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

So how do you implement an additional images-loader into [jQuery's UI-Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) in order to preload the whole content (text + images) of a tab (via Ajax)?

This is my JS for my jQuery UI-Tabs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home_tab').tabs({
      cache: true,

      beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
        ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'POST';

        if ($(ui.panel).html()) {
          event.preventDefault();
        } else {
          ui.panel.html('<div class="tab_loader_home"></div>');
        }

        ui.jqXHR.success(function() { 
        });

        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
        });
      }
    });
});
```

These are my tabs:

```
<div id="home_tab">
<ul id="shadetabs" class="ui-tabs">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#new">New Games</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="sections/ajax/popular.php">Popular Games</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="sections/ajax/top_rated.php">Top Rated Games</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panel_container">
    <div id="new">
        <?php
            include ('./includes/homepage/new_games.inc.php');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

See this question for more info: [Preload images for AJAX content using jQueryUI-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343674/preload-images-for-ajax-content-using-jqueryui-tabs)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "preloading." Do you want the content on the tab before the person actually views the tab? Or...something else? Can you clarify?

Comment: When I click on a tab it loads its contents via Ajax. But it does not load the contents images. I want to load the images through Ajax also (when I click on the appropriate tab). I updated my question.